# What's a good online reference for manipulating Office documents via ActiveX?

Tags: reference, activex, ms-office

I am looking for a reference that covers using ActiveX to open and manipulate Excel (and possibly Word) documents.  I'd prefer an online reference but book suggestions are helpful too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am I missing something? The references are available on MSDN:

- [Excel Object Model Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb149081.aspx)
- [Word Object Model Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb244515.aspx)